# Why are TypedDict types without field and with NotRequired field incompatible?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-3.10, pylance

I am trying to create a few functions which will return values of different TypedDict types. Most of fields in them will be same so I want to generate base dictionary with same function in all cases. However I am getting stumped by typing this correctly.

My idea was to create base type `Parent` and inherit from it, adding only `NotRequired` fields.

```
from typing_extensions import NotRequired, TypedDict

class Parent(TypedDict):
    parent_field: str


class Child(Parent):
    child_field: NotRequired[bool | None]


def create_parent() -> Parent:
    return {"parent_field": "example"}


child: Child = create_parent()
# Error:
# Expression of type "Parent" cannot be assigned to declared type "Child"
#  "child_field" is missing from "Type[Parent]"
```

However this fails since field `child_field` is missing, even though its type is `NotRequired`. Why it fails and how to evade this problem?

EDIT: I am using pylance (so pyright) for typechecking.

`mypy` ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=15a201f20618e94330221df384bdf738)) gives similar error message:

> Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Parent", variable has type "Child")  [assignment]

Comment: What this code means? `child` is not a `Parent` or `Child`. `child` is a `dict`. `create_parent` also returning `dict`. Finally, I checked this code with `python 3.10.2` and no error happens.

Comment: @rzlvmp OP means a `mypy` error (and should mention that in his question). And you should check out [PEP589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/), then you might understand the question.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I expected `mypy` here. But `mypy` also returning different error: `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Parent", variable has type "Child")`. And this error is more reasonable.

Comment: I am using pylance, sorry for not mentioning - will edit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is explained in [PEP589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#type-consistency) explicitly. Let me quote:

> A `TypedDict` type `A` with no key `x` is not consistent with a `TypedDict` type with a non-required key `x`, since at runtime the key `x` could be present and have an incompatible type (which may not be visible through `A` due to structural subtyping). Example:

```
class A(TypedDict, total=False):
    x: int
    y: int

class B(TypedDict, total=False):
    x: int

class C(TypedDict, total=False):
    x: int
    y: str

 def f(a: A) -> None:
     a['y'] = 1

 def g(b: B) -> None:
     f(b)  # Type check error: 'B' incompatible with 'A'

 c: C = {'x': 0, 'y': 'foo'}
 g(c)
 c['y'] + 'bar'  # Runtime error: int + str
```

So, your `Parent` class is **not** assignable to variable of type `Child`, and `pylance` points it out.