# How to add a key to each dictionary in a list of TypedDicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

### Problem

(Python 3.9) I have some inherited [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict)s, as follows:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class Base(TypedDict):
    key: str


class Child(Base):
   extended: str
```

I have a list of `Base` dicts, that I want to extend to be `Child` dicts with the same value for every dict.

```py
base_list: list[Base] = [{'key': 'value'}, {'key': 'value2'}]
```

In the end I want the following:

```py
child_list: list[Child] = [
  {'key': 'value', 'extended': 'sameval'}, 
  {'key': 'value2', 'extended': 'sameval'}
]
```

I am using pylance/pyright.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this elegantly/without a [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)? Note that this is specifically a typing question, I can extend the dict.

### What I Tried

#### List Comprehension

[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197342/how-to-use-list-comprehension-to-add-an-element-to-copies-of-a-dictionary/3197365#3197365) suggests:

```py
child_list: list[Child] = [dict(base,extended='ex') for base in base_list]
```

But, pylance complains:

```
Expression of type "list[dict[str, object]]" cannot be assigned to declared type "list[Child]"
```

I can work around this with a `cast`, but it feels dirty:

```py
a_ex: list[Child] = [cast(Child, dict(base,extended='ex')) for base in a]
```

#### [`NotRequired`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NotRequired)

I thought that I may be able to kludge around it by marking `extended` as `NotRequired`, and then iterating over the list to set the key. Any `Base` object should be a valid `Child` object, right? Nope.

```py
a_ex: list[Child] = a
```

```
Expression of type "list[Base]" cannot be assigned to declared type "list[Child]"
  "list[Base]" is incompatible with "list[Child]"
    TypeVar "_T@list" is invariant
      "extended" is missing from "Type[Base]"
```

I also played around with [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update), but got similar issues as the list comprehension.

Comment: Related (regarding the _"any `Base` should be a valid `Child`"_): https://stackoverflow.com/q/75254643/19770795

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not initialize each `Child` explicitly?

```py
from pprint import pprint
from typing import TypedDict


class Base(TypedDict):
    key: str


class Child(Base):
    extended: str


base_list: list[Base] = [{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value2"}]

child_list: list[Child]

child_list = [Child(key=d["key"], extended="sameval") for d in base_list]

pprint(child_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'extended': 'sameval', 'key': 'value'},
 {'extended': 'sameval', 'key': 'value2'}]
```

This passes `mypy --strict` without a problem and I would be surprised, if Pyright had an issue with this.

**Just to be clear, these two also work:** (based on the same principle)

```py
child_list = [dict(key=d["key"], extended="sameval") for d in base_list]
```

```py
child_list = [{"key": d["key"], "extended": "sameval"} for d in base_list]
```

---

Your first attempt does not work because you are not dealing with dictionary literals or explicitly named arguments there anymore, but with a variable -- `base` in the `for`-loop. I assume that type safety cannot be guaranteed, because a dictionary is mutable, but someone else could iron out the details here, if possible.

In any case, to demonstrate that issue in as minimal an example as possible, consider the following:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class Base(TypedDict):
    key: str


b1: Base = {"key": "value"}  # safe
b2: Base = dict(key="value")  # safe
b3: Base = dict(b1)  # not safe
```

Running this through `mypy` gives the following error for the last line only:

`error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[str, object]", variable has type "Base")  [assignment]`

This is analogous to the error you receive from Pyright in your first list comprehension example. The type checker can only infer that what comes out of that dictionary initialization as `dict[str, object]`.

---

Your second attempt using `NotRequired` should not work either. `Base` is not consistent with `Child`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75254643/19770795) for details.

Comment: Duh, thanks. To expand (since my `TypedDict`s have lots of keys), `[Child(**d, extended="sameval") for d in base_list]` works fine, as expected.

Appreciate the thorough response and the link to the other post. Still figuring out typing in Python!